# Better way to check if a joda.time.Interval spans exactly 1 calendar week (accounting for daylight savings etc)

Tags: java, jodatime

Is there a better way of doing this?

```
boolean oneCalendarWeek = interval.getStart().plusWeeks(1).equals( interval.getEnd() );
```

I guess the following won't work because of the way equals is implemented...

```
boolean oneCalendarWeek = interval.toPeriod().equals( Weeks.ONE );
```

Comment: What is your definition of "exactly one week" here - seven days, zero hours, zero minutes, zero seconds?

Comment: 1 'calendar' week, which varies in duration according to the date and calendar used

Comment: Yes but what I mean is what resolution - if an interval exactly 168 hours (24 *7) apart is an exact week, what about 169 hours (7 days 1 hour)?

Comment: i've removed the word exact as it seems to be causing confusion, i'm not concerned with the precise duration of the week, i'm just interested in whether the interval (specified as a start and end date) represents exactly one *calendar* week (which may or may not be 168 hours)

Comment: i really want to know if the api supports something like my second example which i think is clearer than the first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments:

> i really want to know if the api supports something like my second example which i think is clearer than the first

While the example using `Weeks.ONE` does not work (since `Period.equals()` first checks if the two `Period` instances support the same number of fields, and `Weeks.ONE` only supports one field), this should work instead:

```
boolean oneCalendarWeek = interval.toPeriod().equals( Period.weeks(1) );
```

[Here is a code sample](https://gist.github.com/955224) that tests this for an interval that starts before the start of DST and ends while in DST. However, I'm not 100% sure how this would behave if the start or end time of the Interval fell exactly on the DST boundary.

Comment: Great answer thanks. Shame my example doesn't work, I would've thought the constant `Weeks.ONE` would be more useful as on object which equaled `Period.weeks(1)`.